# Not able to RDP to VMs which are Standard SKU Loadbalanced in Azure

Tags: azure-load-balancer

I had created a standard Public IP and standard Load balancer and 2 VMs and configured NAT rule to map port 5000 to 3389.

But when I try to RDP to I am not able connect to the VM.

The same configuration when I do with Basic LoadBalancer it works fine. Is there any extra configuration I need to do for standard LoadBalancer?

Also there is no NSG configured.

Answer (score 0):

For a Standard Load Balancer NSG is mandatory. Without it NAT rule will not working.